# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type, but struct is already defined

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have already browsed similar points, but they are not relevant to my situation. I have already defined the struct, so I don't understand why I'm getting the "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct tree_node’" compiler error. I seem to have this problem any time I try to access a pointer field of a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Tree_Node {
  char *name;
  struct tree_node *parent;
  struct tree_node *first_child;
  struct tree_node *next_sibling;
} tree_node;

void add_child(tree_node *parent, tree_node *child) {
  tree_node *cur = parent->first_child;
  while (cur != NULL) {
    cur = cur->next_sibling;
  }
  cur = child;
}

tree_node *family_tree() {
  tree_node *father = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
  father->name = "father";
  father->first_child = NULL;
  father->parent = NULL;
  father->next_sibling = NULL;
  tree_node *me = malloc(sizeof( tree_node));
  me->name = "me";
  tree_node *firstbro = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
  firstbro->name = "firstbro";
  tree_node *secondbro = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
  secondbro->name = "secondbro";
  tree_node *son = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
  son->name = "son";
  tree_node *nephew = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
  nephew->name = "nephew";
  add_child(father, me);
  add_child(father, firstbro);
  add_child(father, secondbro);
  add_child(me, son);
  add_child(firstbro, nephew);
  return father;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  tree_node *father = family_tree();
  printf("%s\n", father->name);
  printf("%s\n", father->first_child->name);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct Tree_Node [...] struct tree_node *parent;`. There is no `struct tree_node`.

Comment: It looks like you have already asked this question 10 minutes ago.